# Jquery insertBefore/insertAfter animation not working

Tags: jquery

I made a simple script that allows users to sort divs using up and down buttons.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dZ6rC/5/

Unfortunately, my attempt to animate the move on mouse click does not cause the tags to be moved.

This is my code:

```
$('.up').click(function(){
  var previous = $(this).parent().parent().prev('.item');
  $(this).parent().parent().insertBefore(previous).slideUp();
});
$('.down').click(function(){
  var next = $(this).parent().parent().next('.item');
  $(this).parent().parent().insertAfter(next).slideDown();
});​
```

Can someone figure out why the tags don't move?

Comment: A little follow-up question: http://jsfiddle.net/dZ6rC/7/
don't look at the effects yet, but I tried to hide the up/down buttons when they are irrelevant. When you press 'up' on the middle <div> twice, it gets messy. Anyone a clue? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not hiding the elements before sliding them down so the effect is not seen:

http://jsfiddle.net/dZ6rC/4/

You can just add `.hide` before `.slideDown`.  I think you probably want to improve the animation a bit from there, but just keep this in mind.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. I will accept your answer as soon as I am allowed!

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure what you are trying to accomplish but chaining 3 `parent()` calls is probably not the best way.

I am guessing this solves your problem:

```
$('.up').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('.item').slideUp();
});
$('.down').click(function(){
 $(this).parents('.item').slideDown();
});​
```

If I am missing a requirement please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the a sequence of hide and show:

```
jQuery(html_usr).insertBefore( "#log_row" ).hide().show('blind');
```